# Magento 2 - How to add admin username in order comments on admin action

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, sales-order, magento2.3, admin-panel

I need to add **admin username** in **order comment history** whenever I create

- invoice
- shipment
- and On Cancel order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently did this work through observers

You have to add these event in your module event file `Vendor\Yourmodulename\etc\events.xml`

**For Invoice**

```
<event name="sales_order_invoice_register">
   <observer name="vendor_yourmodulename_observer_addcommentonaction" instance="Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentonaction" />
</event>
```

**For Cancel**

```
<event name="order_cancel_after">
   <observer name="vendor_yourmodulename_observer_addcommentoncancelaction" instance="Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentoncancelaction" />
</event>
```

**For Shipment**

```
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
   <observer name="vendor_yourmodulename_observer_addcommentonshipmentaction" instance="Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentonshipmentaction" />
</event>
```

> Observer files

For **Invoice** Add file in your module `Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentonaction.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer;

class Addcommentonaction implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

    $order= $observer->getData('order');
     //$order->doSomething();
    $authsession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session::class);
    $username = $authsession->getUser()->getUsername();


    $notify = false;
    $visible = false;
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Invoice generated"." (".$username.")", $order->getStatus());
    $history->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
    $history->save();

     return $this;
  }
}
```

For **Cancel** Add file in your module `Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentoncancelaction.php`

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer;

class Addcommentoncancelaction implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

    $order= $observer->getData('order');
     //$order->doSomething();
    $authsession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session::class);
    $username = $authsession->getUser()->getUsername();


    $notify = false;
    $visible = false;
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Order canceled"." (".$username.")", $order->getStatus());
    $history->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
    $history->save();

     return $this;
  }
}
```

For **Shipment** Add file in your module `Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer\Addcommentonshipmentaction.php`

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Yourmodulename\Observer;

class Addcommentonshipmentaction implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {

    $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
    $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    $authsession = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session::class);
    $username = $authsession->getUser()->getUsername();


    $notify = false;
    $visible = false;
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Shipment generated"." (".$username.")", $order->getStatus());
    $history->setIsVisibleOnFront($visible);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified($notify);
    $history->save();

     return $this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to display the admins name also in here -> https://prnt.sc/n891za   Please help me @Muhammad Hasham

Comment: Hi, i achieved the above by extending the Sales\Model\Order addStatusHistoryComment()  function.

Comment: @AskBytes check here https://www.ansarhusain.in/2019/04/display-admin-user-name-who-made-order.htm i have made what you have required

Comment: @AnsarHusain  That's great.  However i found the solution already. thanks for sharing. :)

Comment: bro, its useful for me, i just want the observer and event for 'on-hold', 'hold' ,'cod-confirm', 'cc-paid'  can you please guide me?